# Diagram drawing software 'freehand' style

Tags: windows, gratis, drawing, diagram

A simple question please, I search a free (if possible) software (on windows) which allows to draw this kind of diagrams (as by hand):

[image: picture]

Comment: Welcome. Which operating system? [tag:gratis], or do you have a budget? please read [ask]. The more information that you give us, the more that we can help you. Any features beyond looking like it was drawn by hand?

Comment: please add more details to your question, like the OS it should run on, budget, open source, etc...!

Comment: @Mawg and DJCrashdummy,  thank you for your replies ... I'm newest here :) ... So, I edited my question (OS: windows and a free software if possible)

Comment: It's good to put it in the question, but I also added [tag:Windows] and [tag:graits] tags. Some people search questions by tags, because they know that they can help there. Welcome aboard. I hope that you get a good answer. I would like such an app too.